# Python: grab subset of array where value of first column is equal to specific value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a an array like the following

```
[[1,20,25],[1,45,16],[2,67,81],[3,1,1],[3,23,22]]
```

I want to create a new array from the first array above but taking only the rows where the value of the first column is 1. How can I loop through the entire array checking if the first column of each row is 1 and then adding that row to a new array so that it will look like the following:

```
[[1,20,25],[1,45,16]]
```

Comment: `ar[ar[:, 0] == 1]`

Comment: @MechanicPig  Your suggestion throws a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple.

Comment: @СергейКох Question is labeled numpy, and you shouldn't assume it is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another, not so fancy, way would be this:

```py
arr = [[1,20,25],[1,45,16],[2,67,81],[3,1,1],[3,23,22]]
new_arr = []
for sub_arr in arr:
    # check if the first element in sub_arr is 1
    if sub_arr[0] == 1:
        # if so append it to the new array
        new_arr.append(sub_arr)

print(new_arr)
```